# Ubuntu 12.04 vs Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: versions

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I installed VirtualBox (last version) where I am running Ubuntu  12.04 LTS and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I noticed a significant difference in terms of performance: mainly, the speed. All the tasks I run on Ubuntu 12.04 are faster. I want to do most of my daily work on Ubuntu 14.04 but every task seem slower. I tried them on Vmware Player but the difference is still the same. Why this difference ?

Comment: You sound like you made some measurements; why not include the results here? How do the virtual machines compare? Which install options did you choose, how did you configure the systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to more rigorous benchmarks, there are variations in performance comparing 14.04 to 12.04. In some benchmarks, 12.04 is faster than 14.04. In others, the opposite is true. I will list the test, and the faster ubuntu version:

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?item=ubuntu_1404_desktop&page=article

---

QGears2

Rendering: XRender Extension - Test: Text

**14.04**

---

QGears2

Rendering: XRender Extension - Test: Gears

**14.04**

---

Rendering: XRender Extension - Test: Image Scaling

**14.04**

---

OpenArena v0.8.8

Resolution: 1920 x 1080

**12.04**

---

Unvanquished v0.26.0

Resolution: 1280 x 1024 - Effects Quality: High

**12.04**

---

Unvanquished v0.26.0

Resolution: 1280 x 1024 - Effects Quality: Ultra

**12.04**

---

Unvanquished v0.26.0

Resolution: 1280 x 1024 - Effects Quality: Intermediate

**14.04**

---

Xonotic v0.7

Resolution: 1920 x 1080 - Effects Quality: Low

**12.04**

---

Xonotic v0.7

Resolution: 1920 x 1080 - Effects Quality: High

**14.04**

---

Xonotic v0.7

Resolution: 1920 x 1080 - Effects Quality: Ultra

**14.04**

---

Xonotic v0.7

Resolution: 1920 x 1080 - Effects Quality: Ultimate

**Same**

---

GtkPerf v0.40

GTK Widget: GtkComboBox

**Same**

---

GtkPerf v0.40

GTK Widget: GtkCheckButton

**12.04**

---

GtkPerf v0.40

GTK Widget: GtkRadioButton

**12.04**

---

GtkPerf v0.40

GTK Widget: GtkToggleButton

**14.04**

---

C-Ray v1.1

**14.04**

---

LAME MP3 Encoding v3.99.3

WAV To MP3

**Same**

---

FFmpeg v2.1.1

H.264 HD To NTSC DV

**Same**